# How to ensure that angular $resource uses the following angular $http settings?

Tags: angularjs, cakephp, angularjs-resource, angularjs-http

I am using CakePHP as my backend.

Therefore, if I use `$http`, I need to have the following:

a) the default config must be

```
angularApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
  $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {
      if (data === undefined) {
          return data;
      }
      return $.param(data);
  }
});
```

b) the `ng-model` attribute in the html input must be of the pattern

```
ng-model="data.User.email"
```

In other words, `data.{CakePHPModelName}.{modelattribute}`

**My $http is working perfectly with the CakePHP backend.**

How do I use the angular $resource to be just as successful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$resource` uses `$http` to make all the requests. Any config you want to do on `$http` would be done the same way as if you were using only `$http`.

Comment: I see. What about custom requests?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to add custom requests to your `$resource` you can do that with the `actions` property (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource).

Comment: Oh, I now realize my mistake. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: My mistake was due to a separate issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215420/why-the-difference-in-using-common-and-post-for-changing-the-contenttype-should