# Why the difference in using common and post for changing the ContentType should affect the request payload / form data?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource, angularjs-http

If I use the following:

a)

```
angularApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
  $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {
      if (data === undefined) {
          return data;
      }
      return $.param(data);
  }
});
```

versus

b)

```
angularApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';
  $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {
      if (data === undefined) {
          return data;
      }
      return $.param(data);
  }
});
```

And then when I use a `$http.post` or a `$resource` that uses `POST`

a) is what I want because I get this in the Chrome Dev Tools:

```
  Form Data:
    User[old_password]:xxx
    User[new_password]:yyyy
    User[new_password_confirm]:yyyy
```

b) is NOT what I want because I get this in the Chrome Dev Tools:

```
Request Payload:
User%5Bold_password%5D=xxx&User%5Bnew_password%5D=yyyy&User%5Bnew_password_confirm%5D=yyyy
```

This puzzles me because I expect common to apply for everything including post.

The only difference between a) and b) is b) has

```
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.**common**['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

I am using angular `1.2.6`.

Issue also occurs in `1.2.9`

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your config block type this:

```js
console.log($httpProvider.defaults.headers.post); 

// Object {Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"}
```

As you can see, **$http** already has a default header for a post method.

When you declare common headers **$http** would not override the method specific headers with the common headers. The opposite is the true, first the common headers are applied then the method specific headers override them (if exist).

You can reset the defaults like so:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
```

#### Inside [http.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js) you can see how headers are being merged:

```
function mergeHeaders(config) {
  var defHeaders = defaults.headers,
      reqHeaders = extend({}, config.headers),
      defHeaderName, lowercaseDefHeaderName, reqHeaderName;

  defHeaders = extend({}, defHeaders.common, defHeaders[lowercase(config.method)]);
```

When using [Angular.extend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.extend), the properties of later object overrides the properties of any preceding objects.

Comment: `$http would not override the method specific headers, only extend them.` Extend them means if it is not already assigned, then will assign them. Correct?

Comment: Not exactly , first the common headers are applied then the method specific headers override them (if exist). Look above inside the source code.

Comment: Thank you, I now have a better understanding of this. This means the more finely-grained `.post` always overrides the `.common` properties. Excellent answer, sir!

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer so it would be more clear.